# awk using time difference in miliseconds in the report

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to parse a log file that looks as follows.

```
09/03/2020 00:05:03.364 Aggregated 1000 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:05:03.366 Scheme S20_SessionClassAggregation tree contained 1000 nmes, 500 flushed, 0 remain.
09/03/2020 00:05:03.582 Flushed 1000 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:20:03.598 Aggregated 2000 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
09/03/2020 00:20:03.602 Scheme S20_SessionClassAggregation tree contained 2000 nmes, 1000 flushed, 0 remain.
09/03/2020 00:20:03.860 Flushed 2000 NMEs at a rate of 0 NMEs/sec
```

I need to calculate the timestamp difference from line 3 (`009/03/2020 00:05:03.582`) to line 1 (`09/03/2020 00:05:03.364`) and from line 6 (`09/03/2020 00:20:03.860`) to line 4 (`09/03/2020 00:20:03.598`) in the end of the report, i.e. the time differences between the "Aggregated" and the associated "Flushed" log entries.

I have tried with below `awk` program but it's not working as expected and I am not sure how to do time calculation difference using `awk`.

```
awk '$3 == "Aggregated" {Agg_date=$1" "$2;Aggregated=$4}
     $3=="Flushed" {Flush_date=$1" "$2;Flushed=$4} 
     $4=="S20_SessionClassAggregation" {S20_Flushed=$9}
    {printf Aggregated" "S20_Flushed" "Flushed " "Flush_date" "Agg_date "\n"}' test.txt
```

Expected Results:

```
Aggregated  S20_Flushed   Flushed      Flush_date             Agg_date                  Tme difference between
                                                                                        Flushdate - Agg_date

1000        500            1000       09/03/2020 00:05:03.582 09/03/2020 00:05:03.364  0 min 0 sec 218 ms

2000        1000           2000       09/03/2020 00:20:03.860 09/03/2020 00:20:03.598  0 min 0 sec 262 ms
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use code formatting for example input/output and commands, please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Date/Time manipulation in `awk` is rather limited; you will have to either pipe timestamps to an external shell command for conversion and difference calculation, or use a different tool for the task ...

Comment: @AdminBee ... unless you're using GNU awk which has built in time functions.

Comment: Being as the logged action seems to be run every 15 minutes in crontab, the entire event appears to take place in the first few seconds of a single minute. Do you have any counter-examples? Why not subtract just the seconds in each pair of readings? While you are there, figure out why all your performance measures run at a rate of zero per second.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm aware of these, but I always found the funcionality of `mktime()` rather limited and never found it that useful ... maybe personal prejudice.

Comment: @AdminBee The alternative using mandatory UNIX tools is a shell loop or similar calling `date` once per line as you described in your comment which will be orders of magnitude slower than calling `mktime()`.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, there is always the possibility to write custom-tailored time handling functions in your `awk` program which was what I did in the (rare) cases I used `awk` for tasks that required it. As I said, it might be personal prejudice, and perhaps `mktime()` is more powerful than I currently give it credit.

Comment: @AdminBee There are cases where you're just, say, converting a timestamp from one format to another (e.g. changing `02-Sep-2020` to `20200902`) and then you don't need `mktime()` or `date` or any other time functions but when converting a timestamp to/from seconds since the epoch for tasks like the current one I find `mktime()` to be the best available fit for the job, otherwise you end up trying to include TZs, DST transitions, leap days, and leap seconds over the years into the calculation and it becomes complicated enough that I'd simply never tackle it.

Comment: @EdMorton True, no disagreement on that.

Comment: @AdminBee btw I agree that `mktime()` could have a better API and to that end [I had suggested](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2014-08/msg00024.html) the gawk guys provide a [strptime()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) function which they have now developed and are planning to make available in [a separate library](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/). I couldn't convince them to add it to core gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh yes, _that_ would really improve the usage! Too bad they don't want to include it in the core ...

Comment: @AdminBee Looks like `strptime()` has been in `gawkextlib` for about a year already, https://sourceforge.net/projects/gawkextlib/files/snapshot/. I've never used anything in `gawkextlib` - some day I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do the calculation you asked about using GNU awk for `mktime()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$3 == "Aggregated" {
    aggDt = $1 " " $2
}

$3 == "Flushed" {
    fluDt = $1 " " $2
    aggMs = dt2ms(aggDt)
    fluMs = dt2ms(fluDt)
    difMs = fluMs - aggMs
    print fluDt, aggDt, difMs
}

function dt2ms(dt,      t, ms) {
    split(dt,t,"[/ :.]")
    ms = mktime(t[3]" "t[1]" "t[2]" "t[4]" "t[5]" "t[6]) * 1000 + t[7]
    return ms
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
09/03/2020 00:05:03.582 09/03/2020 00:05:03.364 218
09/03/2020 00:20:03.860 09/03/2020 00:20:03.598 262
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to convert ms to the min/sec/ms format you want and add whatever other info you need in whatever format you need like in your existing script.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the arithmetic. Split out the timestamp on each line, and figure the seconds since midnight (including the milliseconds).

```
function getSecs (Ts, Local, V) {

    split (Ts, V, /:/);
    return (3600 * V[1] + 60 * V[2] + V[3]);
}
```

Call that for each line like

```
Secs[NR] = getSecs( $2);
```

That gives you an array indexed by the line number. The only fix you need is that, if the timestamp jumps backwards, you ran over a midnight and have to add 86400 for that one comparison. That won't work if your log can skip whole days, but that does not look like an issue here.

GNU/awk **does** do date stuff very nicely, with a little work. If you rearrange your data into a string like `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]` and pass that to `mktime()`, you get seconds since the epoch. You can adjust any of the fields (like add 19 to the months value and take 73 off the days) and it will adjust for that internally. You can output any format you like with `strftime()`. (You would need to add the milliseconds back separately.)

Comment: You'd also need to accommodate DST transitions, leap years, and leap seconds if you didn;t use `mktime()` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton Being as the logged records do not indicate a TZ, I would assume they are UTC and don't leap backward or forwards by 3600 seconds in the middle of the night, which would make the data ambiguous anyway. (If the log records 01:20 on the last Sunday in October, that could be DST or not, because the HMS time duplicates anyway -- we get that hour twice -- or get a one-hour gap in March). If we are logging every 15 minutes (as it appears) and looking for time gaps that are sub-second, then arithmetic based on a modulus of one minute or ten minutes is more reliable than DST guesswork.

Comment: Assuming UTC seems reasonable. If not - serves them right for not including a TZ in the timestamp!

Comment: @EdMorton Full ISO 8601 or suffer the consequences!